# How can I edit this code to take into account the current inventory quantity in the product? - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, e-commerce, product

I'm trying to set a reserve order limit when the product has zero (0) inventory and can be reserved. The fact is that with this code I have it works correctly when I have the individually sold box activated. However, what I am looking to achieve is that more than one item can be ordered per order but that it respects both the established quantity of the maximum order limit in reserve as well as the current quantity of product inventory.

That is to say: If the product has an inventory quantity of -5 and the maximum quantity of orders in reserves is -10, it should only be allowed to add to the cart on the simple product page up to a maximum of 5 additional items and that is what is not allowed. I am able to achieve

Below I show you the code I have:

```
function add_reservation_limit_field_to_inventory() {
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $reservation_limit = get_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit', true);

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => 'reservation_limit',
        'label' => 'Límite de pedidos en reserva (dejar vacío para desactivar el límite)',
        'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el límite de pedidos en reserva (número negativo)',
        'desc_tip' => 'Ingrese el límite de pedidos en reserva (número negativo)',
        'value' => $reservation_limit,
    ));
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'add_reservation_limit_field_to_inventory');

// Save the value of the order limit custom field to reservation.
function save_reservation_limit_field($product_id) {
    $reservation_limit = $_POST['reservation_limit'];

    if (empty($reservation_limit)) {
        delete_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit', esc_attr($reservation_limit));
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_reservation_limit_field');


// Verify and limit orders in reserve.
//
//
function limit_orders_on_add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity) {
    // Gets the value of the product's "reservation_limit" custom field.
    $reservation_limit = get_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit', true);

    // Converts the custom field value to integer.
    $reservation_limit = (int) $reservation_limit;

    // Checks if the "reservation_limit" field is set and if the quantity exceeds the limit.
    if ($reservation_limit < 0 && $quantity > abs($reservation_limit)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Sorry, no more backorders are allowed for this product.', 'woocommerce'), 'error');
        return false; // Don't allow adding to cart
    }

    return true;
}

// Check and limit backorders when adding to cart
function check_reservation_limit_before_add_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if (!limit_orders_on_add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity)) {
        return null; // Avoid adding to cart if the limit is not met
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_reservation_limit_before_add_to_cart', 10, 3);
```

I have tried several forms of the code but none of them have had the expected result.

Update with the solution code:

```
///////// Agregar un campo personalizado al producto para la cantidad máxima de reservas en el configurador de productos///////
//
////// Seccion que agrega el campo personalizado
function add_reservation_limit_field_to_inventory() {
    $product_id = get_the_ID();
    $reservation_limit = get_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit', true);

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => 'reservation_limit',
        'label' => 'Límite de pedidos en reserva (dejar vacío para desactivar el límite)',
        'placeholder' => 'Ingrese el límite de pedidos en reserva (número negativo)',
        'desc_tip' => 'Ingrese el límite de pedidos en reserva (número negativo)',
        'value' => $reservation_limit,
    ));
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'add_reservation_limit_field_to_inventory');

// Guardar el valor del campo personalizado de límite de pedidos en reserva.
function save_reservation_limit_field($product_id) {
    $reservation_limit = $_POST['reservation_limit'];

    if (empty($reservation_limit)) {
        delete_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit', esc_attr($reservation_limit));
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_reservation_limit_field');

///// Sección de restricción según el número declarado en el campo personalizado
//
// Función para verificar y limitar pedidos en reserva.
//
//
function limit_orders_on_add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity) {
    // Obtiene el valor del campo personalizado "reservation_limit" del producto.
    $reservation_limit = get_post_meta($product_id, 'reservation_limit', true);

    // Convierte el valor del campo personalizado a entero.
    $reservation_limit = (int) $reservation_limit;

    // Obtiene la cantidad actual en inventario.
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

    // Verifica si el campo "reservation_limit" está establecido y si la cantidad excede el límite.
    if ($reservation_limit < 0 && ($quantity + abs($stock_quantity)) > abs($reservation_limit)) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Lo sentimos, no se permiten más pedidos en reserva para este producto.', 'woocommerce'), 'error');
        return false; // No permite agregar al carrito
    }

    return true;
}

// Verificar y limitar pedidos en reserva al agregar al carrito
function check_reservation_limit_before_add_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if (!limit_orders_on_add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity)) {
        return null; // Evitar agregar al carrito si no se cumple el límite
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_reservation_limit_before_add_to_cart', 10, 3);
```

Comment: please also share the screenshot of product edit page inventory section where you have set the custom field

Comment: Ready, this issue has been resolved.

You just had to add this additional condition:

`if ($reservation_limit < 0 && ($quantity + abs($stock_quantity)) > abs($reservation_limit)) {`

Below, I share the complete code in case anyone else needs it at some point, thank you very much!

Comment: @SeoSiteSoft Thankyou!